# getIdentifier() always returns 0

Tags: android, android-resources

I am trying to get the ID of a string with value "Hello" from strings.xml doing to following:

```
getContext().getResources().getIdentifier("Hello", "string", getContext().getPackageName());
```

It returns 0. Why is this returning 0?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you're passing the string *value*, while you should pass the *resource name* of the string.

Look at the method signature: [`getIdentifier(String name, String defType, String defPackage)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html).

When the resource is not found, `0` is returned which is consistent with what you're experiencing.

**Edit:**

1. Use of `getIdentifier()` is discouraged - to quote the reference:

   > Note: use of this function is discouraged. It is much more efficient to retrieve resources by identifier than by name.
2. I know no direct way of getting the ID of a string based on value of the string in question. However I've seen two workarounds/hacks:

   1. Name all strings for which you want the lookup to be performed like this: `stringN` where `N` is for example 0-based integer incremented for each of the strings. You end up with ugly names like `string0`, `string1`, etc. Then you do the lookup yourself - you iterate over `N`, create string ID: `stringN`, get its value and check for a match. This is ugly in my opinion.
   2. Use [Typed Array](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#TypedArray) resource and put all your strings there. It's basically the same as method 1, but avoids creation of nasty, polluting resource names.

Comment: You are right. Is there a way to look up the ID from the value?

Answer (score 1):

In case package name in Manifest differs you won't get an identifier because your package name is incorrect, in order to get correct package name for resources dynamically you should use:

```
String rPackageName = mContext.getResources().getResourcePackageName(R.some.wellKnownResource);
```

'rPackageName' is a package name that you should pass to the function

```
getIdentifier(String name, String defType, String defPackage)
```